# How to Block UDP port in devices

Tags: applications, udp

am trying to disable webrtc on the root level
Is there any guide to do that
want to stop IP leaks while using a proxy it's easy in chrome but not for other apps..

Comment: A local VPN app should be able to block all UDP traffic except the one required. That would even work without root.

Comment: alternative if I want to use my proxy?